# Set Cursor using div id

Tags: vbscript, cursor, set

I'm trying to set a cursor in a field. That's all I want it to do. The div ID is "ct131_ct104_ct107". Here is what I'm working with:

```
<td class="ParamLabelCell"><span>FLN Year/Julian (YYDDD) and Serial (NNNNN)</span></td>
<td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07">
```

Can it be done in VBScript?

Comment: Let me clarify some more: I'm using Macro Express to write a macro. I'm using the external script where I'm adding my own code. I have a form on a site with multiple boxes where information can be entered. I'm trying to get the cursor to start in that field without having to tab to the field. Since the number of fields changes, I'm trying to see if I can put the cursor where I want it by using the div id (or any other method that would work).

Comment: `<div>` are page structure elements, not user input elements. Use the ID of an actual input element or select an input element contained in that `<div>`.

Comment: So the ID, like I mentioned above (ct131_ct104_ct107) I can't use to refer to the box for cursor placement? Or I can use said ID?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Focus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952640.aspx) method can be used to position the cursor in elements that take user input (e.g. input boxes or textareas). I don't think setting the cursor on other elements is possible in in VBScript.